# Test a serial port (RS232) in Linux OS

Tags: linux, serial-port

I would like to test RS232 in term of functionality and reliability in Linux OS.

Any idea about this? Is there something like script that can test it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make a loopback plug, send a bunch of data, see if you get everything back as expected.  Don't forget about the control lines if you care about those.

Comment: What @Brad wrote, but if the UART or USART has an internal loopback capability, then that should always be performed first (since it's a simpler test that does not involve the line transceivers).

Comment: Thanks Brad. @sawdust, can you briefly describe how to perform the loopback test? sorry if i am asking a basic question. I am new to linux OS. Thanks!

Comment: btw, @Brad, how do you make a loopback plug? what is required for this?

Comment: Check a pinout sheet and connect the rx pins to the tx.

Comment: @Brad, a jumper wire will do the thing?

Comment: @YiXuChee, Yes, exactly.

Comment: okay i think i got it. Thank you!!

Comment: If the UART hardware supports it, then the call `ioctl(fd, TIOCMBIS, TIOCM_LOOP);` should activate the internal loopback.  Other `ioctl` calls possible are described [here](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6226)